# "access denied due to Access Control Lists" при загрузке RDLC отчётов

Tags: iis

Как запустить на IIS7 отображение отчётов rdlc спомощью `ReportViewer`? При вызове страницы из IIS получаю такую ошибку:

> `You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials you supplied (access denied due to Access Control Lists). Ask the Web server's administrator to give you access to 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS10.MSSQLSERVER\Reporting Services\ReportManager\home.aspx'.`

Когда запускаю из под сервера студии, всё отображается! Как всё настроить, чтобы заработало?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Извиняюсь, решилось просто: у меня route был настроен на имя Reports  наверно, как-то перехватывался путь, я его поменял и всё за работало.